# I want the values entered in the gui to change the values in the script of code that the gui runs

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

I have this code and I want the values I enter in the gui, them being "number of loops", "initial value" and "barrier" to change the equivalent values with those names in `brcus.py` and `brceu.py`. Also I want the text box for those values and the buttons which run the code to be in the same gui window.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)                
        self.master = master
        self.init_window()        

    def init_window(self):
        master = tk.Tk()
        self.master.title("Barrier Reverse Convertible")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        menu=Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu=menu)
        file=Menu(menu)
        file.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.client_exit)
        menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file)
        edit = Menu(menu)
        edit.add_command(label="Undo")
        menu.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=edit)
        quitButton=Button(self, text="Quit", command=self.client_exit)
        quitButton.place(x=5, y=250, height=25, width=50) 
        root.geometry("300x300")

        def callback():
            exec(open("brceu.py").read())

        def callback1():
            exec(open("brcus.py").read())  

        button=tk.Button(self, text="American Barrier", command=callback1)
        button.place(x=5, y=3, height=50, width=100)
        button=tk.Button(self, text="European Barrier", command=callback )
        button.place(x=205, y=3, height=50, width=100)

        def show_entry_fields():
            print("Number of Loops: %s\nInitial Value: %s\nBarrier: %s" % (e1.get(), e2.get(), e3.get()))        
        tk.Label(master, text="Number of Loops").grid(row=0)
        tk.Label(master, text="Initial Value").grid(row=1)
        tk.Label(master, text="Barrier").grid(row=2)
        e1 = tk.Entry(master)
        e2 = tk.Entry(master)
        e3 = tk.Entry(master)
        e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
        e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
        e3.grid(row=2, column=1)
        tk.Button(master, text='Quit', command=master.quit).grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=tk.W, pady=4)  
        tk.Button(master, text='Show', command=show_entry_fields).grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=tk.W, pady=4)
        button.pack    

    def client_exit(self):
        exit()

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("700x600")
app = Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two methods to use values from one script in another.

(1) in `brceu.py` you have to uses `sys.argv` to get arguments and then you can run it in system

```
python brceu.py arg1 arg2
```

In code you can use

```
subprocess.run("brceu.py arg1 arg2", shell=True)
```

or

```
os.system("brceu.py arg1, arg2")
```

(2) In `brceu.py` you have to put code in function(s) - ie. main()

```
def main(arg1, arg2):
    # ... code ...
```

and then you can use it like other modules

```
import brceu

brceu.main(arg1, arg2)
```

In `brceu.py` you can even use

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
   import sys

   main(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
```

so it can be run also as

```
python brceu.py arg1 arg2
```